# A class that represents a key combination

Tags: c++

For a little game of mine I have created a Key.h file that should allow representation of a key press combination. A key combination is basically some key represented by its virtual key code stored in `int _key`and the state of modifier keys - shift, control, alt and windows keys. In case that key combination is used for typing, the key also stores the character that it should produce in `_c`.

```
class Key
{
private:
    bool _shift;
    bool _ctrl;
    bool _alt;
    bool _win;
    int _key;
    char _c;

public:
    constexpr Key()
        :
        _shift(),
        _ctrl(),
        _alt(),
        _win(),
        _key(),
        _c()
    {}

    constexpr Key(const Key& key)
        :
        _shift(key._shift),
        _ctrl(key._ctrl),
        _alt(key._alt),
        _win(key._win),
        _key(key._key),
        _c(key._c)
    {}

    constexpr Key(bool shift, bool ctrl, bool alt, bool win, int key, char c)
        :
        _shift(shift),
        _ctrl(ctrl),
        _alt(alt),
        _win(win),
        _key(key),
        _c(c)
    {}

    Key& operator= (Key& key)
    {
        _shift = key._shift;
        _ctrl = key._ctrl;
        _alt = key._alt;
        _win = key._win;
        _key = key._key;
        _c = key._c;
    }

    bool operator== (const Key& key) const
    {
        return (_shift == key._shift && _ctrl == key._ctrl && _alt == key._alt && _win == key._win && _key == key._key, _c == key._c);
    }

    bool operator!= (const Key& key) const
    {
        return !(*this == key);
    }
};
```

Are there any design flaws or some obvious things that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would start by fixing the warnings, one of which is an actual bug:**

---

**[1]
Operator = not returning a value**

```
main.cpp: In member function 'Key& Key::operator=(Key&)':
main.cpp:50:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
main.cpp: In member function 'bool Key::operator==(const Key&) const':
```

**Also:** your operator= gets `Key& key` instead of `const Key& key`

**Wait!** don't rush to fix it. You can just eliminate it altogether and rely on the default assignment operator that does the same job ("rule of zero").

---

**[2] using comma in the long list of equality check -- an actual bug**

```
main.cpp:54:100: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
         return ( ... && _win == key._win && _key == key._key, _c == key._c);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Wait!** don't rush to fix it. We will use std::bitset so the entire operator== would become simpler.

---

After fixing the warnings above we can proceed for improvements.

**[3] Use `std::bitset` for the bool flags**

Instead of:

```
bool _shift;
bool _ctrl;
bool _alt;
bool _win;
```

Use:

```
enum SpecialKeys {SHIFT, CTRL, ALT, WIN, _SIZE_};
std::bitset<SpecialKeys::_SIZE_> specialKeys;
```

---

**[4] No need for assignment operator and copy ctor (rule of zero).**

Just use the defaults.

---

**Proposed fixed code:**

```
#include <bitset>

class Key {
    enum SpecialKeys {SHIFT, CTRL, ALT, WIN, _SIZE_};
    std::bitset<SpecialKeys::_SIZE_> specialKeys;
    int _key = 0;
    char _c = 0;
public:
    constexpr Key() {}
    constexpr Key(bool shift, bool ctrl, bool alt, bool win, int key, char c)
        : _key(key), _c(c)
    {
        specialKeys[SpecialKeys::SHIFT] = shift;
        specialKeys[SpecialKeys::CTRL]  = ctrl;
        specialKeys[SpecialKeys::ALT]   = alt;
        specialKeys[SpecialKeys::WIN]   = win;
    }

    bool operator== (const Key& key) const
    {
        return (specialKeys == key.specialKeys && _key == key._key && _c == key._c);
    }

    bool operator!= (const Key& key) const
    {
        return !(*this == key);
    }
};
```

Comment: Ah, very constructive. Since you mentioned the rule of zero, should I just completely remove the copy constructor or request it from compiler with `= default` ?

Comment: Just use the defaults by not declaring at all, no need for `= default` in this case.

Comment: Don't use `_SIZE_` as an identifier in your code - that's [reserved for the implementation for any use](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3) (so could even be a macro).

Comment: I like this version more, in the upcoming C++20, you would even be able to default the operator<=>